# open_counter returned with error 19

Tags: performance, cpufreq, tools

I am trying to use perf tool. I have installed ubuntu 12.04 on Pandaboard. After booting up the system, installed linux-tools. Which installed linux-tools-3.0.0-25. running the perf, gives following error.

> perf_3.0.0-25 stat ls

```
  Error: open_counter returned with 19 (No such device). /bin/dmesg may provide additional information.

  Fatal: Not all events could be opened.
```

How do I fix the above problem?
Did anyone get the perf to work on any ubuntu releases on Pandaboard? I can use any build if perf and cpufreq are available.
I am a newbie to linux/ubuntu. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In order to have perf tool working you should have enabled performance counter in your kernel build, then recompile kernel and place new image into proper place (depends on how you boot your system)

I am running it on my Tegra2 Harmony board without any problem after enabling the performance counters in kernel.